# Slow generation of Excel file - Interop libraries?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I need to generate an Excel file with 4500 rows. 
I made a code which goes cell by cell and it is very slow. 
The data is coming from SQL 2008 server and I read it with ObjectResult and BindingSource classes. Yes it works but for large amount of data is just not reasonable to wait so long.

Is there a better way to export SQL data from a query and export it to Excel(xls) file in reasonable time with C#/WPF/.NET 4?

```
    public static int WriteToXLS(BindingSource data, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = Utils.getMSExcelApplicationObject();
        int ishod = 0;
        string destination;
        string[] headings = MyClass.getColumnHeadings();
        Range range;
        int i = 1, j = 1;
        string execPath;
        Workbook book;
        Worksheet sheet;

        try
        {
            destination = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\DATA_" + GodishnaPrograma.Default.Year + ".xls";
            rtb.Text = "Снимам податоци во " + destination + ", почекајте!";
            execPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            book = app.Workbooks.Add();
            sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

            for (i = 1; i <= headings.Length; i += 1)
            {
                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, i];
                range.Value = headings[i - 1];
            }

            j += 1;

            foreach (MyClass item in data)
            {
                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 1];
                range.Value = item.Field1;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 2];
                range.Value = item.Field2;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 3];
                range.Value = item.Field3;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 4];
                range.Value = item.Field4;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 5];
                range.Value = item.Field5;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 6];
                range.Value = item.Field6;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 7];
                range.Value = item.Field7;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 8];
                range.Value = item.Field8;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 9];
                range.Value = item.Field9;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 10];
                range.Value = item.Field10;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 11];
                range.Value = item.Kod_1;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 12];
                range.Value = item.Kod_2;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 13];
                range.Value = item.Kod_3;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 14];
                range.Value = item.Kod_4;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 15];
                range.Value = item.Kod_5;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 16];
                range.Value = item.Kod_6;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 17];
                range.Value = item.Kod_7;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 18];
                range.Value = item.Kod_8;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 19];
                range.Value = item.Kod_9;

                range = sheet.Rows.Cells[j, 20];
                range.Value = item.Kod_10;

                j += 1;
            }

            book.SaveAs(destination);
            book.Close();

            return ishod;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rtb.Text += " WriteToXLS(): " + ex.Message + ", " + ex.Data;
            ishod = -1;
            return ishod;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly slow? Database querying or library which operates that data and composes Excel components?

Comment: If csv format is acceptable ... ms excel can read it directly no need to build the xls file programatically.

Comment: @vasiloreshenski Yes we had that option, but the bosses here like it fancy looking. If I could open the csv with code and put every data piece into its appropriate cell. Is it possible?

Comment: Office Interop is a bad library to use anyways. It requires Excel be installed on the client machine, which isn't always guaranteed. It often gives inexplicable error messages. It's slow. And it has to manage a separate process (Excel) in order to do anything. You're far better off using a native library to generate your Excel file, such as [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus), [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml), [Aspose](https://products.aspose.com/cells/net), [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) etc.

Comment: @Vlad you can open the csv file directly with excel (csv is native format in excel) which will display the csv file as regular table, not charachter delimited file ... so you will have well formatted and nice looking table ... if you insert the headers in the csv file you will have the same file which you are creating programatically.

Comment: You can't really style a CSV file. If you stick with XLS or XLSX, you will maintain complete control over how the resulting file looks.

Comment: Instead of individually accessing each cell & setting its value - what you can do to speed things up is create an object array, insert all values into that array & assign the array to the required range.

Comment: The process interop is not exactly cheap.  If you do that for each individual cell, and don't turn off automatic recalc either, then yes, it adds up fast.  It is one heck of a big gun to shoot a csv mosquito, the CsvHelper library is popular.

Comment: @PaulF good idea. Can you recommend me a sample code?

Comment: All you need to do is create a suitable object array _object [,] myData = new object[dataLength+1,20];_ - then populate it with your data - so headings go in 1st row, data in second - just replace the excel stuff in your code with array assignments. Then, after the foreach loop, assign the array to the Range : _sheet.Range["A1:B20"].Value2 = myData;_ - that way you just have a single access to the Excel process.

Comment: The range specified in my last comment should match the array size - so should be something like _"A1:T4501"_ (4501 = the number of rows in the array - data length + 1 - from your original sentence).